# Apply Transformation from Mapping Node to UVs?

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I'm using the mapping node in the shader editor to create different UVs for curves without needing to convert them to mesh/unwrap them first (I'm doing hair cards, all the cards are on one texture). Is there a way to apply the transformations I'm doing in the mapping node to the UVs once I've converted the curve to a mesh? Usually when I use this technique I'm baking the texture to UVs I've handmade, but now I want to do the opposite, keep the texture and "bake" the UVs. Is that possible?